# An array as a navigation path for another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

let´s say I have this array A `[1, "testSuites", 20, "testCases", 1]`
I'd like to navigate through an array B using the array A as a navigation route.

For example:

```
console.log(arrayB[1]["testSuites"][20]["testCases"][1])
```

Please help me! Oh and **without** using **eval**

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's a simple problem.

Comment: try `A.reduce((p, key) => p[key], B)` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce` with `try/catch`

```
//var arrayA  = [1, "testSuites", 20, "testCases", 1];
function evaluate( arrayA, arrayB )
{
   try
   {
     return arrayA.reduce( (acc, c) => acc[c], arrayB); 
   }
   catch(e) { 
      //return null or undefined if the arrayA has invalid values
   }   
}
```

For setting the value

```
function setValue( arrayA, arrayB, value )
{
   try
   {
     arrayA.reduce( (acc, c, i) => {
        if ( i == arrayA.length - 1 )
        {
            acc[c] = value;
        }
        return acc[c];
     }, arrayB); 
   }
   catch(e) { 
      //return null or undefined if the arrayA has invalid values
   }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the perfect solution. BTW what does (acc, c, i) do?

Comment: @LuisDanielLopezSandi read about `reduce` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce . `acc` is the accumulator, `c` is the current item in iteration and `i` is the index.

Comment: Oh thank you for the info. I have a question about the ","
What does the " acc[c], arrayB " do? Is arrayB replaced in acc?

Comment: in that expression acc[c] is continuation of first parameter (reduce's callback function) `(acc, c) => acc[c]` while arrayB is the second parameter - initial value of `acc`

Comment: so is it like saying: return arrayA.reduce( function (acc, c) { return acc[c], arrayB } )
?

Comment: No, arrayB is outside the function, second parameter of reduce. `arrayA.reduce( function (acc, c) { return acc[c]}, arrayB  ) `

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the actual object is truthy or take an object as default value for not given properties.

```
A.reduce((object, key) => (object || {})[key], B)
```

---

For setting a valuey, you use the path and reduce the path by walking the given object. If no Object exist, create a new property with the name, or an array.

Later assign the value.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var last = path.pop();

    path.reduce(function (o, k, i, kk) {
        return o[k] = o[k] || (isFinite(i + 1 in kk ? kk[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {});
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

var test = [];

setValue(test, [1, "testSuites", 20, "testCases", 1], "Mr. Foo");

console.log(test);
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked!
I really need to study more js. I don't know what "(o, k, i, kk)" really does

Comment: that are the variables of the callback, in order: the actual object, the key, the index of the `path` array and the reference to the path array.